# How can i configure services per mapped IApplicationBuilder?

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-1.0, asp.net-core-middleware

In the owin I configure different services for mapped application builders like below:

```
using (WebApp.Start("http://localhost:8001", app =>
{
    app.Map("/context1", appBuilder => {
        appBuilder.UseWebApi();
        appBuilder.ConfigureIoc();
    });
    app.Map("/context2", appBuilder =>{
        appBuilder.UseNancy();
        appBuilder.ConfigureIoc();

    });
}))
{
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

In the asp.net core, I need to configure services per mapped application builder but all registered services applied to all mapped application builder. I will configure services per appBuilder.

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddScoped<IFooService, DefaultFooService>();
    services.AddMvc();
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
{
    app.Map(new PathString("/context1"), appBuilder  =>
    {
        // appBuilder.AddMvc();
        // appBuilder.ConfigureIoc();
    });
    app.Map(new PathString("/context2"), appBuilder  =>
    {
        // appBuilder.UseNancy();
        // appBuilder.ConfigureIoc();
    });
}
```

Comment: Is your question "how can I have multiple separate `ServiceCollection`s that are used by separate routes"?

Comment: @NateBarbettini Yes, separate branch(route)

Comment: Does this post help? http://andrewlock.net/forking-the-pipeline-adding-tenant-specific-files-with-saaskit-in-asp-net-core

Comment: @NateBarbettini unfortunately there is nothing about of configure services